# Finding zeros of a complex function in SciPy/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've been told that the method scipy.optimize.newton() will solve complex functions so long as the first derivative is provided. I can't make it work. The documentation for newton() mentions nothing of complex functions. Could someone show me how one would find the roots of a function like f(z) = 1 + z^2 in SciPy? I need to solve something much more complex, but a simple example will help me immensely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of the use of [`newton`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) with a complex function, in an IPython session:

```
In [1]: def func(z):
   ...:     return 1 + z*z
   ...: 

In [2]: def deriv(z):
   ...:     return 2*z
   ...: 

In [3]: from scipy.optimize import newton

In [4]: newton(func, x0=1+1j, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12)
Out[4]: 1j

In [5]: newton(func, x0=-2j, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12)
Out[5]: -1j
```

Note that `newton` doesn't handle `x0` being a point where the derivative is zero:

```
In [6]: newton(func, x0=0, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12)
/Users/warren/local_scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py:119: RuntimeWarning: derivative was zero.
  warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
Out[6]: 0.0
```

Also, if your function returns real values for real arguments, be sure to pass in a complex value for `x0`.  Otherwise the function is stuck on the real axis:

```
In [21]: newton(func, x0=0.5, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-2feb08057c57> in <module>()
----> 1 newton(func, x0=0.5, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12)

/Users/warren/local_scipy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.pyc in newton(func, x0, fprime, args, tol, maxiter, fprime2)
    159             q1 = func(*((p1,) + args))
    160     msg = "Failed to converge after %d iterations, value is %s" % (maxiter, p)
--> 161     raise RuntimeError(msg)
    162 
    163 

RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 50 iterations, value is -0.870752774435
```

Increasing `maxiter` won't help:

```
In [22]: newton(func, x0=0.5, fprime=deriv, tol=1e-12, maxiter=1000)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 1000 iterations, value is -0.0895687261655
```

Comment: From my experience it also seems necessary to provide at least a first derivative, since the secant method otherwise used won't cope with complex valued `x0` via some error message that `x0 >= 0` cannot be checked for complex numbers. Mathematically valid, but it might be a bug in the implementation...

Comment: *"...it might be a bug in the implementation... "* See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10103